# Put data from url into dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I got this table code

```
<table id="tabel_komponen" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID Komponen</th>
            <th>Nama Komponen</th>
            <th>Ekuivalen SKS</th>
            <th>Ekuivalen Jam</th>
            <th>Indikator</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="badan_tabel" >                     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I use the dataTable Plugin to make it looks good, here's the code

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tabel_komponen').DataTable();
} );
```

I want to get the data for the table from this URL : http://paramadina.net:18011/data/psc_komponen

I already try this code

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tabel_komponen').DataTable();
} );
var table = $('#tabel_komponen').DataTable( {
    ajax: 'data.json'
} );

alert( 'http://paramadina.net:18011/data/psc_komponen'+table.ajax.url() );
```

but it dont worked...And I want to add an edit button into the table

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `http://paramadina.net:18011/data/psc_komponen/data.json` is the URL where JSON file is located, then use the code below:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tabel_komponen').DataTable({
       ajax: 'http://paramadina.net:18011/data/psc_komponen/data.json'
    });
});
```

As noted by [@davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252844/put-data-from-url-into-datatable/32257430#comment52440321_32257430), unless `paramadina.net` allows cross-domain requests, the code above will fail. You need to allow such requests or use JSONP or other alternative methods to get the data.

Comment: I have the weird feeling OP also are facing a CORS issue.